# Problems with WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations

Any help/explanations will be highly appreciated:

---

This works:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == Sin[t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1,
     WhenEvent[Abs[t x[t]] > 1, {x'[t] -> -x'[t]}]}, 
    x, {t, 0, 8}][[1]];

xt = x /. sol;

Plot[xt[t], {t, 0, 8}];
```

---

This does not:

```
TT = t;

sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == Sin[t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1,
     WhenEvent[Abs[TT x[t]] > 1, {x'[t] -> -x'[t]}]}, 
    x, {t, 0, 8}][[1]];

xt = x /. sol;

Plot[xt[t], {t, 0, 8}]
```

---

This crashes the Kernel:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == Sin[t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1,
     WhenEvent[(Abs[x[t]] > 1) && (x[t] > 5), {x'[t] -> -x'[t]}]}, 
    x, {t, 0, 8}][[1]];

xt = x /. sol;

Plot[xt[t], {t, 0, 8}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second example doesn't work because the `t` in `TT = t;` is *another* `t`, outside the scope of the `DSolve[]`.

Your third example doesn't kill the kernel here :

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == Sin[t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1, 
     WhenEvent[(Abs[x[t]] > 1) && (x[t] > 5), {x'[t] -> -x'[t]}]}, 
    x, {t, 0, 8}][[1]];

xt = x /. sol;

Plot[xt[t], {t, 0, 8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but the `WhenEvent[]` clause isn't working. I guess that what is happening is that the first part of the `ÀND` clause rises an "exception" each time it occurs and then the second part is checked, but it's false.
So, simply reversing the `AND` clauses works:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == Sin[t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1, 
     WhenEvent[(x[t] > 1.5) && (Abs[x[t]] > 1), {x'[t] -> -x'[t]}]}, 
    x, {t, 0, 8}][[1]];

xt = x /. sol;

Plot[xt[t], {t, 0, 8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please note that I've changed the `x[t]` value where the event is met only to make the effect more visible.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The third example still crashes the kernel. I am using Mathematica 9 on a Mac running OS X 10.9, maybe it is just the version.

Comment: I'm using Mma v9.0.1 on Win.

Comment: @user11311 The third example works for me (Mma 9.0.1, Mac OS X 10.8.5).

Comment: Thanks! Then it is an issue with 9.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it was a scope issue. I solved the second example, this works:

```
TT[t_] := t;
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == Sin[t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1,
   WhenEvent[Abs[TT[t] x[t]] > 1, {x'[t] -> -x'[t]}]}, 
x, {t, 0, 8}][[1]];
xt = x /. sol;
Plot[xt[t], {t, 0, 8}];
```